# Ho do I perform an active sleep/timeout in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, settimeout, sleep

I know that Javascript is single-threaded and blocking the event loop is not the right way. But I was wondering if there is a way to perform something like `sleep(5000ms)` to **simulate** code that takes a long time to perform.

I need this for debugging purposes.

Comment: Do you want to block event loop or it shouldn't block event loop?

Comment: As per my understanding you want to convert your huge computation to async. you can use setTimeout. as well as async(https://caolan.github.io/async/) library will be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short and simple, You can use while loop to check for time elapse.

```js
function stopForN(ms){
    var sts = Date.now();

    while((Date.now() - sts) < ms){}console.log('finished');
}
stopForN(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `while` loop to simulate sleep like below,

It will block the event loop for approximately `5s`.

```js
function sleep(interval) {
    let d = new Date().getTime();
    while (true) {
        let d1 = new Date().getTime();
        if (d1 - d >= interval) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
sleep(5000);
console.log('after interval');
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure this is what you really want, but I use this library in tests to make the test think time has passed, it's very useful when you're testing code with timers.

I use something like this:

```
//before the test
var clock = lolex.install();

//make the code think a second had passed
clock.tick(1000);

//after the test
clock.uninstall();
```

https://github.com/sinonjs/lolex